# WITHDRAWN: How can those with a "current mods" preference ensure *all* mods get elected?

Tags: discussion

UPDATE: PLEASE IGNORE THIS QUESTION.  I CAN'T DELETE IT ON META...

Ok, when I'm wrong, I'm wrong.  I accept that, and have a lot of practice at it :)

I do want to say a few things however:

1. Frankly the biggest problem with my question is the idea that there is an "anti-incumbent slate" or a strong negative preference.  There isn't.  There isn't anybody on the list who is sufficiently odious as to make me go elsewhere for my daily fix.  Even those who might step on my house, if elected, would actually be good mods.
2. I do still believe there is a fundamental flaw with having one vote and four slots.  STV is designed to fill fewer slots than preferences - and having to choose one mod to receive no support whatsoever is odious to me.
3. Mason, in particular, is a very important balance within the moderator quadumravte. I for one would be sad if, in the general excitement about Caleb, Wax, and ElEndia, he were forgotten.  I doubt there is anyone here who would actively not want want him - I'm concerned that a fluke in preferences could accidently knock him out of contention.  Again, what's the worst that happens? Someone else equally good gets his slot :)
4. I was not attempting to "tell anyone how to vote."  I believe, and still believe, there is a lot of support for our existing moderators - but as anyone who has ever been in a GOTV effort can tell you, support isn't enough: you actually have to get people to vote.  Going through the most likely scenarios, I was afraid of "bad consequences." But you know what? There aren't really any.  My concern was simply that for the majority of us who wish we had four votes instead of one, that group behaviour wouldn't have an unintended consequence.  As such, I proposed a voluntary scheme to coordinate - not collude.  I'm not Henry Kissinger, I'm not Machiavelli.  (And if anyone calls me a "community organizer," I will get svidgen to go step on your house!)
5. I thank the community for realizing my heart was in the right place, even if my brain was not.

---

So, we have four moderator slots and three votes.  At the risk of disclosing personal information, I'm going to make clear my intention - I want the existing set of moderators to be returned to office, with no disruption to the moderator status quo.

Here's my question and my concern: How should a person vote to maximize that outcome?

Imagine, for example, if this slate has vast majority of the site's support - and let's pretend that 9 out of 10 voters think that way. Furthermore, lets assume that Slate 1 (consisting of mods A, B, C, and D) has 90% of the vote, and Slate 2 (Mod F, the "anti-incumbent" mod candidate) is a negative preference for the same group.  Furthermore, let's assume that 10% gives their full vote to F.

There is a very real concern that, without coordination or a fourth vote preference, A, B, and C will get 90% of the vote, D won't get any, and F will get the fourth slot.

Here's the concern - how does a group organize itself to ensure A, B, C, and D get support to reflect the will of the community?  While the obvious solution would be to petition for a 4th slot (Here's looking at @Shog9!), is there another way in which we can ensure that we don't have an [Election of 1800 problem - i.e. where Jefferson & his running mate tie!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1800#Breakdown_by_ticket)?

Comment: At the moment it might not really matter. The four current mods have clear leads over on the election thread, with Warren and Peter Turner essentially tied for 5th at about half the votes the top 4 have...

Comment: Yeah, I saw the trend, but I can see people going Oh yeah, Caleb, Wax, El, and oh wait, I don't have a vote left for Mason.

Comment: And, frankly, I'll put it out there: Mason, you're the one I'm worried about.  What you do is probably the most quiet, but also exceedingly important.  I've looked at how much you review and vote - but yours tends not to be the "Closed By" as often as the other three.  That doesn't make you any less valuable, just less visible!  I want you in that mix.

Comment: @MasonWheeler the concern is valid as people who had huge primary vote counts have not been elected in the past, basically due to the free rider problem. The example I would turn to would be Brad Larson 2011 SO election: http://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary he came in 6th after coming in 3rd in the primary.

Comment: @AffableGeek: Fair enough.  And if someone asked about that, I'd say, if you think that a moderator's job is to close posts that the community isn't voting to close, don't vote for me.  Because I tend to not do that, except for obvious trollery or equally obvious duplicate questions, if I happen to see them first.

Comment: It's hard not to see a tiny bit of irony in this post, given the main site's subject matter.

Comment: I think you're over thinking the problem that STV is already designed to fix. The biggest problem I see is people trying to trick the system by "organizing among themselves". That's what the system already does is organize everybody's votes, and it's more balanced at doing so than people's first impressions.  Vote _your_ first, second and third preferences and let it do the balancing.

Answer (score 9):

The reason you don't get four votes is that the likelihood of you needing one is almost nil.

The way that STV works is that first votes are counted first.

IF someone reaches a specified threshold (don't ask me how it works, it's all done on a computer), they are elected. If no one reaches the threshold than the candidate with the lowest total is eliminated.

Now we branch.

- IF no one was elected on the first pass, the first votes of the people who voted for the eliminated candidate are thrown out and their full vote goes to their second selection.
- If a candidate is elected in a round, everyone each vote for that candidate becomes fractured. The computer calculates exactly how much the candidate needed to win outright and divides that among the people who voted for the candidate. That amount is then given to each of their second selections.

This goes on until the required candidates are elected, in each round either a candidate reaches the threshold or is elected by meeting a threshold that is set in each round.

The frequency with which an election exhausts all choices that it would merit a fourth choice seems to be quite rare. (I've also been *told* that Meek STV only supports three choices, but that is unsourced at this time).

While the scenario you outline is possible (where essentially 10% of the vote elects the fourth candidate), it's highly unlikely. There is likely to be enough variance in people's top 3 that there is no need for collusion.

The biggest danger IMO is that a single candidate will be thought of to be the favorite by a large majority of voters and be left off their ballots because they believe that enough other people will vote for that candidate first. This has happened before, **my simplest advice would be to make sure that you vote for your top choices, regardless of what you think anyone else will do.**

Comment: All that to say, getting a fourth slot might make you feel better, but ultimately, even if you had a fourth slot, you'd still be leaving a candidate off because the odds of the process getting to your fourth vote are very slim.

Comment: I bolded the last sentence. The system is designed for every user to vote for their top choices. Trying to get your desired outcome by "tricking" the system will likely fail and may even result in the opposite effect.

Comment: I'm more used to forms of STV in which you have as many votes as there are candidates, but the general purpose of STV is that you can simply vote your preferences, without having to worry about what other people are doing.

Answer (score 6):

Even giving the benefit of the doubt to the motivation for suggesting this, it's collusion, pure and simple.

Let's take the case you seem to be worried about: Caleb, Wax, El get elected, but someone other than Mason gets the 4th spot.  Your question and self-answer imply that you're *sure* whoever that 4th person is would be inferior to Mason and that the people who voted for that 4th person shouldn't have.

To my mind, people can and should decide for themselves who to vote for, and if that means someone you want to see elected isn't, you should have faith in the other voters (and in whoever gets elected) instead of trying to tell people who to vote for.

Comment: Not trying to tell people who to vote for - only suggesting a voluntary scheme if others share my beliefs, and trying not to feel bad about who I don't pick :)